# When using "Trace Into" in Delphi Community edition, it does not show properties in the Object Inspector

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, trace, delphi-10.4-sydney, object-inspector

I'm using Delphi Community edition 10.4 and I'm trying to find an error in my code. I have used Delphi 7 where if you use "*Trace Into*" it helps you find your error.

When using the Community edition, it shows me a bunch of random code and when I press <kbd>F8</kbd> and it starts my program, it doesn't show anything in the Object Inspector.

Comment: I don't understand - in Delphi 7 the Object Inspector also hides by default when running the program.

Comment: not when using trace into

Comment: When you "trace" your code, you are in the "debug" layout. By default it shows the variables so somehow you changed the default. It is easy to make it visible again: Use menu / View / Debug Windows / Local variables. Don't forget to save the desktop layout so that you get it the next time.

Comment: thats exactly the problem, it is on but it shows nothing. just process is not accessible

Comment: that happens to me a lot with methods that jump into a "proc"-reference; anything in the jump isn't accessible anymore

Comment: Are you sure that you're talking about the Object Inspector?  You'd expect to see the values of variables in the Local Variables window and/or the Watch List window (if you've set a watch).  But not when you press F8 to start the program, as that wouldn't immediately take you to anywhere with variables.  Try putting a breakpoint in your code where there is a variable you want to inspect, and start the program with F9 (Run).